# I bought a bottle of spirits with the security tag intact. Have I committed theft?

Tags: united-kingdom, theft, shoplifting

I bought a bottle of spirits from a local supermarket, when I got home I noticed the [BottleLox](https://www.catalyst-direct.com/media/1080/bottlelox-product.jpg?width=1400&mode=max) anti-theft cap hadn't been removed.

I paid for my shopping (including the bottle!) at a self-service till, and the shop-assistant verified I was over 18 to purchase alcohol, however she didn't remove the tag, and nothing beeped at me when I left the store. The tag itself was around the neck of the bottle, inside a cardboard box.

- Did I commit theft when I left the shop with their security tag? Or....
- Since I legitimately purchased the bottle, and the tag was (at time
  of purchase) intrinsically part of the bottle, can I assume I also
  purchased the tag?

Comment: Won't you have to take it back to get the tag removed without danger of breaking the bottle?

Comment: @WeatherVane - no, the mechanism is very simple. Took me less time to remove the tag than it did to drive home from the supermarket.

Answer (score 2):

Theft in the U.K. requires "intention of permanently depriving the other of it" ([Theft Act 1968](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1968/60), s. 1).

A person not knowing they have a thing in their possession does not have the intention of depriving someone of that thing.